# Tikz table conversion image

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this but I am looking to make an image similar to the one attached. I want to show converting from one table to another with a condition. Is there a formal name for this process?

[image]

Comment: Which process is that? I ask you because, depending on its nature, it might be possible to automate the conversion of the elements and the generation of the new tables.

Comment: I'm not sure if latex can do transformation equations?

Comment: I am not familiar with those. Perhaps if you describe them or provide a link to them we can check.

Comment: http://www.bulletphysics.com/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtTransform.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## With TikZ

You can do this using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to buid each matrix with the help of a `matrix of math nodes`:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning}

\tikzset{ 
common/.style={
  text depth=1.25ex,
  text height=2.5ex,
  inner sep=0pt
  },
table/.style={
  matrix of math nodes,
  common,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,draw=black,text width=2em,align=center},
  nodes in empty cells,
  }
}

\newcommand\TabHead[4]{
\path
  let
  \p1=#1,
  \p2=#2
  in
  node[
    text width=\x2-\x1-2\pgflinewidth,
    yshift=-\pgflinewidth,
    align=center,
    anchor=south,
    draw,
    fill=green!10,
    common
  ] 
  at (#3.north) 
  {#4};
}
\newcommand\DrawArrow[2]{
  \node (texto) at #1 {$\Rightarrow$};
  \node[above=0pt of texto] {$\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}#2\end{array}$};
}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (mat1) [table]
{
  P & X & Y & Z \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
};
\TabHead{(mat1.west)}{(mat1.east)}{mat1}{Base Text}

\matrix (mat2) [table,right=2cm of mat1.north east,anchor=north west]
{
  P & X & Y & Z \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
};
\TabHead{(mat2.west)}{(mat2.east)}{mat2}{Other Text}

\matrix (mat3) [table,right=2cm of mat2.north east,anchor=north west]
{
  P & X & Y & Z \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
};
\TabHead{(mat3.west)}{(mat3.east)}{mat3}{Another Text}

\DrawArrow{($ (mat1.east)!0.5!(mat2.west) $)}{\Delta X \\ \Delta Y \\ \Delta Z}
\DrawArrow{($ (mat2.east)!0.5!(mat3.west) $)}{\Delta X \\ \Delta Y}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## TikZ-free

You can also do this without TikZ using `array`:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand\TableData[2]{%
{
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}
  $\begin{array}{@{}|c|c|c|c|@{}}
  \hline\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor{green!10}\mbox{#2}} \\\hline#1\hline
  \end{array}$%
  }%
}

\newcommand\DrawArrow[1]{
$\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\begin{array}{c}
#1
\end{array} \\
\Rightarrow
\end{array}$%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\TableData{
  P & X & Y & Z \\\hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\hline
  2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
  3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
}{Base Text}
&
\DrawArrow{\Delta X \\ \Delta Y \\ \Delta Z}
&
\TableData{
  P & X & Y & Z \\\hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\hline
  2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
}{Other Text}
&
\DrawArrow{\Delta X \\ \Delta Y}
&
\TableData{
  P & X & Y & Z \\\hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\hline
  2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
}{Another Text}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```